# Condition for dictionary key-value in Typescript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a dictionary :

```
dict = {

"a": 1,
"b" : 2

}
```

I need to implement a condition that returns true if "a" is 1 and "b" is 2 and so on if I'm to add more key-value pairs.

How should I approach this?
I searched and found `Object.keys()` and  `Object.values()`  but I'm not sure about how to logically do this

Comment: Could you elaborate on the so on? Would an object with more key-value pairs look like { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 } ?

Comment: `if (dict.a === 1 && dict.b === 2)`?

Comment: @richytong yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for syntax using which you can iterate over the object keys and value?
If so please refer below -

```js
dict = {
"a": 1,
"b" : 2
}

for(let key in dict) {
    console.log(key, dict[key])
    if (dict[key] === key) { 
        // write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to write this as `for (const key in dict)` just so that people don't monkey with the key.

Comment: yeah good approach, but the habit of using `i` everywhere makes me write here as well. Anyways corrected

Comment: @ABGR agree for point 1, you can check the working example for point 2

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Object.entries(dict).forEach(([key,value]) => {
if(value === key) {...}
})
```